# Java, Image not showing on an Applet

Tags: java, image, swing, applet, japplet

I'm very new to Java, especially Applets/GUI.  I am doing an assignment on Image Map with Hot Spots and I've already ran into issues just getting the image to show up on the applet.

From the class textbook it shows adding an image to an Applet as a fairly simple operation yet I cannot get it to show up (the string for the drawString does show up).  I've tried with a BufferedImage and URL with no luck either.  Any help on where I'm going wrong is greatly appreciated!  FYI, the CarDash.jpg is copied into my project folder.

```
public class ImageMap extends JApplet{

//Display image on applet window
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Image pic = getImage(getCodeBase(), "CarDash.jpg");
    g.drawImage(pic, 0, 30, this);
    g.drawString("Car Dashboard", 20, 30);

 }
}
```

Comment: Don't load resources inside `paint`, this will slow down you painting process.  Try using `BufferedImage pic = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/CarDash.jpg"))`; instead.  I'd also discourage the use of applets generally while learning, they can be very unforgiving

Comment: Ok thx Mad, I'll try that out.  Unfortunately this assignment calls for using an Applet

Comment: Should I load the image in an Init method?

Comment: Yes, `init` would be preferred. Also have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) as you are breaking the paint chain

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at those because what you suggested isn't working either.  I seem to be doing something wrong somewhere

Comment: The solution will depend on the relationship between the image, the source code and the compiled classes.  Are you using an IDE?  Are you generating a Jar file?  How are you running the applet?  Are you using a html page to load the applet?

Comment: Yes I'm using Eclipse.  The assignment tells us to use the IDE's applet viewer for right now.  I believe next assignment we start doing more and will use a Browser

Comment: Place the image either in the `src` directory or the `resources` directory and try using `getClass().getResource(...)` again

Comment: That was it!  The pic wasn't in the SRC folder it was in the main project folder.  I thought that's where getClass().getResource() & getImage()  looked but I guess not?

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  Oh, just noticed *"Unfortunately this assignment calls for using an Applet"*  Yes, definitely refer the teacher to the article.  They are being negligent by trying to teach applets, and should be ashamed of themselves.

Comment: Lol I just do as I'm told Andrew.  This is an online class and I'm honestly not too happy with the way it's set up.  I really like the instructor and I know he did not set up the class structure so after the semester I will for sure refer him to that article!  Is it obsolete?

Comment: Never mind I guess I should've read that article first.